# why does my request hang when trying to get a user by email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Microsoft Graph API SDK to fetch a user from my AD B2C tenant like so:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    var clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(Globals.ClientId)
        .WithTenantId(Globals.TenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(Globals.ClientSecret)                
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientapp);

    return new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
}

public static User GetADUserAsyncByEmail(string email)
{
    var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
    var user = graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync().Result;
    return user;
}
```

But my request just hangs!  What am I doing wrong? I am able to use DeleteAsync() fine for example using the same mechanism.

Comment: If you are using the Result function from the main thread the application can hang.
Try using the await syntax : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await

Comment: i tried it with async await first: same issue.

Comment: *i tried it with async await first: same issue* -> you probably didn't refactor all the way up the call chain

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public static async Task<User> GetADUserAsyncByEmail(string email)
{
    var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
    var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
    return user;
}
```

Comment: As long as the OP did not understand why his/her code was blocking, you could improve this answer adding an explanation on why the code was problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting hang because your `GetADUserAsyncByEmail` does return the `User` and in order to return its user it is waiting fot the result of the asyncronous function `graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync()`.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync().Result; // Accesing to the Result you are waiting for the `async` completion
```

In order to avoid that function hang/block your thread, you should make it asyncronous.

Note: This code is similar to [the await operator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

```cs
public static async Task<User> GetADUserAsyncByEmail(string email)
{
    var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
    var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
    return user;
}
```

So when you call it from your thread it is non-blocking until you want it (you really need its results)

```cs
Task<User> fetchingUser = GetADUserAsyncByEmail("jane.doe@gmail.com");
// Do other stuff until you need to access the `User` object
User jane = await fetchingUser; // If if was not already finished, it will wait/block until retrieved.
Console.WriteLine(jane.Address);
```

Comment: yep I tried exactly this. The issue seems to be the api.

Comment: Can you confirm your code did not get stuck in the `Task<User> fetchingUser = GetADUserAsyncByEmail("jane.doe@gmail.com");` but did it when it got to `User jane = await fetchingUser;`? If so, the API would work fine.

Comment: thanks actually I put it in a try..catch this time and there is an exception generated from the request failing.